# Haskell Typeclass Instance based on canonical view

Tags: haskell

As a self assigned exercise of sorts, I'm playing around with implementing an algebra based numeric type heirarchy.

I'd like to specify that if a structure can be viewed in a canonical way as something that satisfies one of my typeclasses, then it should be an instance of that typeclass as well. To that end I've tried essentially the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies,
               FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}
class AbGp s a where
  plus :: a -> a -> s -> a
  zero :: s -> a
  minus :: a -> a -> s -> a
class View a b c | a c -> b
  view :: a -> b
instance (View s s1 a, AbGp s1 a) => AbGp s a
  plus x y s = plus x y (view s)
  zero = zero . view
  minus x y s = minus x y (view s)
```

`s` should be thought of as holding the definitions of the operations in the group, and `a` as the type of the elements in the group.

But this doesn't work, which isn't surprising, but what I want to do now is:
Suppose I know that some type `s`, say `s` that represents a `Ring`, can be mapped canonically to `s1` which is a datastructure I already have an instance for as an `AbGp`, then I would like `s` to also be automatically an instance of `AbGp`. How can I do this?

I'm thinking of doing the following, if it'll work, but I'd like to know if there is a better way:

```
instance (AbGp s1 a) => AbGp (s1,b) a where
  -- ...
```

Comment: The instance that the compiler picks for `View` on invocations of `view` necessarily depends on the type variable `c`, but `view` doesn't mention this type. Change `view` to `view :: Proxy c -> a -> b` or the like, and your code will work. However, you should be careful with an instance like `AbGp s a` - it will overlap with every other instance, which will make type errors harder to read. You can probably avoid this with your latter formulation, which seems to me to be a better choice.

Comment: @user2407038 as you answered the question in that comment, care to post it as an answer?